# Unable to access enum in groovy script using intelij ide

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, enums

I am learning enum in groovy and am using the intellij ide , following is the code , its pretty simple ,

```
package com.groovy.practice

 enum daysOfWeek{Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday}
//println daysOfWeek.values()

Range daysOfWeekRange = daysOfWeek.Sunday..daysOfWeek.Saturday
println daysOfWeekRange.size()

assert daysOfWeekRange.contains(daysOfWeek.Wednesday)

println daysOfWeekRange.getFrom()
println daysOfWeekRange.getTo()
```

on running this in intellij idea , I am getting the below error ,

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: daysOfWeek for class: com.groovy.practice.Set5Excercise
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: daysOfWeek for class: com.groovy.practice.Set5Excercise
    at com.groovy.practice.Set5Excercise.run
```

My Intellij version is 2017.2.3
Groovy Version is groovy-2.6.0-alpha-1.

This same code is working absolutely fine in groovyConsole

Could someone please help ?

Comment: how you run it in intellij? maybe you running as a  groovy class ?

Comment: Use a capital letter `DaysOfWeek`

Comment: @tim_yates , Thanks Tim , changing the case worked , I am pretty new to groovy could you please explain what happened here , and one more thing it works even with lower case in the groovyCosole , so could it mean that its a bug in intellij ide ?